# How to Format JavaScript Long String Date

Tags: javascript

I am using this code to export dates of current week days

```
var arr =[];
var curr = new Date(); 
var first = curr.getDate() - curr.getDay();
for (var i = 1; i < 6; i++) {
    var next = new Date(curr.getTime());
    next.setDate(first+1 );
    arr.push(next.toString());

}
```

but the output looks like `Mon Nov 09 2015 01:43:57 GMT-0800 (Pacific Standard Time)` in the array of

> ["Mon Nov 09 2015 01:43:57 GMT-0800 (Pacific Standard Time)", "Mon Nov
>   09 2015 01:43:57 GMT-0800 (Pacific Standard Time)", "Mon Nov 09 2015
>   01:43:57 GMT-0800 (Pacific Standard Time)", "Mon Nov 09 2015 01:43:57
>   GMT-0800 (Pacific Standard Time)", "Mon Nov 09 2015 01:43:57 GMT-0800
>   (Pacific Standard Time)"]

Can you please let me know how I can format the date() to get only
`Mon Nov 09 2015` and remove  `01:43:57 GMT-0800 (Pacific Standard Time)`?

Thanks

Comment: Take a look at http://momentjs.com/

Comment: I am not familiar with moment but can it do this? I mean getting dates of all day in current week?

Comment: Overkill.  You've already got what you need (with a slight issue with `first + 1` - it should be `first + i`).  Look at the answer from @laszlokiss88

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the [toDateString()](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_todatestring.asp) method on the Date object.

```
arr.push(next.toDateString());
```

Answer (score 1):

Its simple. I am using your code. just use toDateString() method of Date()

```
var arr =[];
var curr = new Date(); 
var first = curr.getDate() - curr.getDay();
for (var i = 1; i < 6; i++) {
    var next = new Date(curr.getTime());
    next.setDate(first+1 );
    arr.push(next.toDateString());
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```js
document.write(new Date().toDateString());
```